# Corollary of Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_n :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of real-valued functions satisfying

1. $|f_n(x)| \leq C$ for all $x$ and $n$
2. $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \leq \delta(|x-y|)$ for all $x,y$ and $n$, where $\delta(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} \delta(x) = 0$.

Is it possible that $\liminf_{n} f_n(x)$ is a *discontinuous* function?

Arzela-Ascoli gives the existence of some subsequence which converges uniformly to some continuous function $f_\infty$, but I don't see why that necessarily should have to relate to the $\liminf_{n} f_n(x)$.

Comment: What have you tried?  The equicontinuity seems to do it.  If you have $f_{m}(x_{0})$ close to $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x_{0})$ and $y$ is close to $x_{0}$, then $f_{m}(y)$ must be (uniformly) close to $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x_{0})$ as well...

Comment: The equicontinuity gives $-\epsilon + f_n(x_0) \leq f_n(y) \leq f_n(x_0) + \epsilon$ for all $y$ in a sufficiently small ball around $x_0$, for all $n$. The inequalities are preserved by taking $\liminf$, so we get $-\epsilon + \liminf f_n(x_0) \leq \liminf f_n(y) \leq \liminf f_n(x_0) + \epsilon$, which gives us the continuity. In particular, compactness of the space and uniform boundedness plays no role. Is it that simple?

Comment: Your argument is correct but some boundedness assumption is required to make sure that lim inf is real valued!